# How can I make JSF 2.0 page with .jsf extension?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

The default one is xhtml. I want to change it to .jsf.

Is this possible using facelets/jsp or using anyone of these two?

Comment: Is there some particular problem you're trying to solve?  Having a hard time figuring out why this would be necessary, so not sure exactly how to respond.  When I was a JSF n00b, I did that once and all I managed to do was make myself a heap o' trouble since nothing expects it to be setup that way...  I wasted a terrible amount of time making it all work just right when I should have just left it alone.  :-)

Comment: I'd suggest to learn the basic Servlet API as well. It puts a whole world open as to how JSF works under the covers.

Comment: @Brian yes , i want the URL in the client browser to be `http://... /myapp/home.jsf` like that.  Can't this be done at all? I use Netbeans IDE 6.8 BTW :)

Comment: @BalusC I read the Servlet API, Its classes and methods but unable to find how its related with the Url of the client browser. Can u suggest me from where I can learn what you suggested me to learn please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your asking about changing the servlet mapping so you can go to http://website/index.jsf instead of something like http://website/faces/index.xhtml. To do this change your url-pattern in your web.xml .

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I didn't have to change the .xhtml file extension of the index file in my project for this to work.